# Adding Event in Android Calendar

Tags: android, events, android-calendar, android-syncadapter

```
private void setEvent(){        
    long startMilis = 0;
    int mCalId = 1;
    long endMilis = 0;
    Calendar beginTime = Calendar.getInstance();
    beginTime.set(2013, 1, 29, 9, 10);
    startMilis = beginTime.getTimeInMillis();  
    Calendar endTime = Calendar.getInstance();
    endTime.set(2013, 1, 30, 10,10);
    endMilis = endTime.getTimeInMillis();

    ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(Events.CALENDAR_ID, mCalId);
    values.put(Events.DTSTART, startMilis);
    values.put(Events.DTEND, endMilis);
    values.put(Events.TITLE,"Special Event");
    values.put(Events.DESCRIPTION, "Group Activity");
    values.put(Events.EVENT_TIMEZONE, "America/Los_Angeles");
    Uri uri = cr.insert(Events.CONTENT_URI, values);
    Toast.makeText(this, "Event Added", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

This is snippet of my code where i want to add Event to the android calendar. Code works fine.

But when tested on device, **The specified event does not actually get added and does not appear in calendar**.Code is totally Error free and i have provided necessary permissions.

Can someone please tell me where exactly i am doing wrong.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I am having same issue. It only happens for me on my company account, on my personal they get added just fine.

Comment: So just figured out what was happening in my case. The event was added to the Contacts' Birthday and Events calendar by default. If I unsubscribe from that and US Holidays then it worked. It seems like you pass in an explicit mCalId so maybe that's not your issue.

Answer (score 3):

If there are no errors, but nevertheless the event does not appear in the Calendar, 
I would suspect that the culprit is the `mCalId = 1` assignment.

A device can have multiple calendars. It's not guaranteed that the one with id == 1 is the primary one (and even if you used the primary one, the user may have events in multiple different calendars -- e.g. personal and work).

So, it depends on what you want to do exactly. You should either:

- use the primary calendar (the one with [`IS_PRIMARY`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CalendarContract.CalendarColumns.html#IS_PRIMARY), but see caveat above), or
- have the user select a calendar first (only if more than one is found when querying the [Calendars table](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CalendarContract.Calendars.html)) and then using that `calendar_id` from then on.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are usin wrong Uri, i use this in my app:

```
    Uri EVENTS_URI = Uri.parse(CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI.toString());
    ContentResolver cr = getActivity().getContentResolver();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    values.put("calendar_id", 1);       
    values.put(Events.TITLE, recordatorio);
    values.put(Events.ALL_DAY, 1);
    values.put(Events.EVENT_LOCATION, lugar);
    values.put("dtstart", calDate.getTimeInMillis());
    values.put("dtend", calDate.getTimeInMillis());
    values.put(Events.DESCRIPTION, observaciones);
    values.put("availability", 0);
    values.put(Events.HAS_ALARM, true);     
    values.put(Events.EVENT_TIMEZONE, TimeZone.getDefault().toString());

    Uri uri = cr.insert(EVENTS_URI, values);
// to get the Id Event          
    long eventID = Long.parseLong(uri.getLastPathSegment());
```